# Auto approve the topic after assignment approved in learndash

Tags: php, wordpress, learndash

So I am working on a learndash topic page in which I added the assignments for my students but I want when the instructor approves the student assignment so it will autocomplete that topic and I only wish to for the assignment page not any other topic page.

So can anyone suggest to me anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want like add assignment to students from teachers page
need to special table in database and assignment database 
when add assignment like pdf will then upload it to server
will insert to assignments table these data -> title & discreption & link file to download it students page
so in this way , you need select new assignment to show it in student page

Comment: I guess you didn't get my question, I am talking about the Learndash plugin that we used in WordPress to create an LMS website and there I need this custom solution because it is not presented in the default settings. And I don't want to add assignments I only want that if the Instructor approves any assignment in the backend so it will automatically complete that particular topic on student side.

Comment: @AvinishKr.SinghRajawat 
you need then build relational table between orders of particular and students in database